# What does "arrangements" mean here?

Tags: word-meaning

What does "arrangements" refer to in this context?

> You have returned from a holiday with an English-speaking tour company. You spent two weeks travelling by coach but were unsatisfied with the arrangements, the itinerary and the accommodation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case "arrangements" means the way the trip was organised. You did not like how the trip went, what happened, how you travelled, how you stayed and so on.